# PL SQL data is in numeric format (20211023) i want to use the where clause on date column +30days

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

```
Select * from Table where date >='20210911' + 30days
```

the date is in numeric format and what to pull the records for a specific date +30days of specific date

Could you please help

Answer (score 2):

Uh. Never store dates into any other datatype column but `DATE`. Now you first have to "convert" it, then do the arithmetic.

```
select * 
from some_table
where to_date(date_column, 'yyyymmdd') > date '2021-09-11' + 30
                            --------
            apply format mask that matches data in that column
```

Hope (should I say *pray*?) that all values represent valid dates. Nobody prevents you to store e.g. `20228579` into it, and - applying `to_date` to it - results in

```
SQL> select to_date('20228579', 'yyyymmdd') from dual;
select to_date('20228579', 'yyyymmdd') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL>
```

Once again, bad, BAD idea!

Comment: Sorry i confused a lot

Comment: how to apply between clause ( where date_column between date '2021-09-11' and date '2021-09-11'+30

Answer (score 0):

> how to apply between clause ( where date_column between date '2021-09-11' and date '2021-09-11'+30

If you have an index on the column that you want to use then convert the value to a date then add 30 days to it and convert it back to a number:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Table_Name
WHERE  date_number BETWEEN 20210911
                   AND     TO_NUMBER(
                             TO_CHAR(
                               TO_DATE(20210911, 'YYYYMMDD')
                               + INTERVAL '30' DAY,
                               'YYYYMMDD'
                             )
                           )
```

If you don't have an index and want a simpler query then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Table_Name
WHERE  TO_DATE(date_number, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN DATE '2021-09-11'
                                        AND     DATE '2021-09-11' + INTERVAL '30' DAY
```

---

The best solution would be to convert your numeric column to a `DATE` column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD date_column DATE;
UPDATE table_name SET date_column = TO_DATE(date_number, 'YYYYMMDD');
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN date_number;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Table_Name
WHERE  date_column BETWEEN DATE '2021-09-11'
                   AND     DATE '2021-09-11' + INTERVAL '30' DAY
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2529318865e9cfd661d56b4f9d88834a)*